# Spark - read JSON array from column

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 2.11, I've the following Dataset (read from Cassandra table):

```
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|id         |attributes                                                 |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|YH8B135U123|[{"id":1,"name":"function","score":10.0,"snippets":1}]     |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is the printSchema():

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- attributes: string (nullable = true)
```

The `attributes` column is an array of JSON objects. I'm trying to explode it into Dataset but keep failing. I was trying to define schema as follow:

```
StructType type = new StructType()
                .add("id", new IntegerType(), false)
                .add("name", new StringType(), false)
                .add("score", new FloatType(), false)
                .add("snippets", new IntegerType(), false );
        
ArrayType schema = new ArrayType(type, false);
```

And provide it to `from_json` as follow:

```
df = df.withColumn("val", functions.from_json(df.col("attributes"), schema));
```

This fails with MatchError:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType@43756cb (of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType)
```

What's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the schema this way :

```
val schema = ArrayType(
  StructType(Array(
    StructField("id", IntegerType, false),
    StructField("name", StringType, false),
    StructField("score", FloatType, false),
    StructField("snippets", IntegerType, false)
  )),
  false
)

val df1 = df.withColumn("val", from_json(col("attributes"), schema))

df1.show(false)

//+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
//|id         |attributes                                            |val                     |
//+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
//|YH8B135U123|[{"id":1,"name":"function","score":10.0,"snippets":1}]|[[1, function, 10.0, 1]]|
//+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

Or for Java:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.*;


StructType schema = createArrayType(createStructType(Arrays.asList(
    createStructField("id", IntegerType, false),
    createStructField("name", StringType, false),
    createStructField("score", FloatType, false),
    createStructField("snippets", StringType, false)
)), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the schema as a literal string instead:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "val",
    from_json(
        df.col("attributes"),
        lit("array<struct<id: int, name: string, score: float, snippets: int>>")
    )
)

df2.show(false)
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
|id         |attributes                                            |val                     |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
|YH8B135U123|[{"id":1,"name":"function","score":10.0,"snippets":1}]|[[1, function, 10.0, 1]]|
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

If you prefer to use a schema:

```
val spark_struct = new StructType()
                .add("id", IntegerType, false)
                .add("name", StringType, false)
                .add("score", FloatType, false)
                .add("snippets", IntegerType, false)

val schema = new ArrayType(spark_struct, false)

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "val",
    from_json(
        df.col("attributes"),
        schema
    )
)
```

Two problems with your original code were: (1) you used the reserved keyword `type` as a variable name, and (2) you don't need to use `new` in `add`.

Comment: This doesn't compiles for me as from_json expect the 2nd argument to be a DataType rather than Column.. I'm using 2.11

Comment: @Seffy then try the second method ?

Comment: Tried, same error.. What do u meant no need to use 'new'? My coding is Java, not Scala..

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood... [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51636509/14165730) might be helpful for java

Comment: Now no exception, but the from_json hangs for ever.. Dataset contains just 1 row, how clue to check what's going on there? Running with local.